# Closure Dev Mode & Chrome Packaged App -- "document.write() is not available in the sandbox of packaged apps"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-closure-library

I'm running into issues in development mode with Closure as the security policies for my Chrome Packaged App (i.e., v2 manifest file) are restricting things called in the Closure bootstrap process (e.g., when I load the app using the uncompiled dev code, I get "document.write() is not available in the sandbox of packaged apps").

Answer (score 2):

The following code is what I eventually used and it works great for running Closure in Dev mode within Chrome's Packaged App framework.

In closure/goog/base.js, overwrite goog.global.CLOSURE_IMPORT_SCRIPT as follows:

```
goog.global.CLOSURE_IMPORT_SCRIPT = function(src) {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  goog.global.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  return true;
};
```

Comment: You can select your own answer as the answer.