# Google Closure and Chrome packaged apps: compatibility?

Tags: javascript, google-closure, google-chrome-app

I am using Google Closure and and I am trying to make a Chrome packaged app.

My call to `goog.require` causes an error:

```
Uncaught document.write() is not available in packaged apps.
```

The culprit is in `base.js`

```
goog.writeScriptTag_ = function(src) {
  if (goog.inHtmlDocument_()) {
    var doc = goog.global.document;

    // If the user tries to require a new symbol after document load,
    // something has gone terribly wrong. Doing a document.write would
    // wipe out the page.
    if (doc.readyState == 'complete') {
      // Certain test frameworks load base.js multiple times, which tries
      // to write deps.js each time. If that happens, just fail silently.
      // These frameworks wipe the page between each load of base.js, so this
      // is OK.
      var isDeps = /\bdeps.js$/.test(src);
      if (isDeps) {
        return false;
      } else {
        throw Error('Cannot write "' + src + '" after document load');
      }
    }

    doc.write(
        '<script type="text/javascript" src="' + src + '"></' + 'script>');
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Is Google Closure incompatible with Google Chrome packaged apps?
Closure has so many benefits for large Javascript projects it is really hard to give up such a valuable tool.

EDIT: I know that if the Closure Compiler is used in addition to the Closure libraries, there is no goog.require, but that clearly makes development and debugging much more difficult.

Answer (score 1):

[Closure Dev Mode & Chrome Packaged App -- "document.write() is not available in the sandbox of packaged apps"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15279728/closure-dev-mode-chrome-packaged-app-document-write-is-not-available-in)

As long as you run it uncompiled or don't compile with advanced compilation you have to re write the doc.write with document.createElement("script");

So replace te doc.write line with:

```
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = src;
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  goog.global.document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
  return true;
```

Advance compiled code should not need this as it puts all the used code together in one file.

Comment: It this guaranteed to work? It seemed that when I tried this for dynamically loading Javascript on another project the scripts executed asynchronously in indeterminate order.

Comment: I confirmed this observation. It may work for small files, or something else, but the javascript is loaded and evaluated non-sequentially.

Comment: That must be the reason google uses document.write. You could try calcdeps.py and create <script tags for all files needed. You can use output list to get a list and then create <script tags to load all needed js files before using them. goog.require should detect the file is already loaded and will not perform the document.write. https://developers.google.com/closure/library/docs/calcdeps#opts

Comment: Yes, and this is what I wound up doing. It's not a pretty solution, and I hope eventually there is a better one, but calcdeps and inserting into the html works.